# Where can I see the next time the function starts?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I have a function in Azure on Python that runs every 12 hours:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 */12 * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to see when the next launch will be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to see the trigger time directly, but since your time trigger is every 12 hours, so we can get to know the next trigger time indirectly by the request history in "Monitor" of the function.
[image]

In the "Monitor" tag (here in the screenshot above, I deployed a time trigger function triggered every minute), we can see the running history of the function, since we can see the last running time, so we can also know the next trigger time(the last time +12hours).

By the way, if we want to use the monitor, we need to enable application insights when we create the function app.
[image]

Hope it would be helpful to your question~

**Update:**

We can also see the time of next launch in "Live Metrics Stream", shown as below:

1. click "Monitor" --> "Live app metrics"
   [image]
2. we can find the next time in the message in "Sample Telemetry"
   [image]

Comment: Yes, it is, but I wonder if the information about the next launches is displayed somewhere.

Comment: Hi @kshnkvn, I have updated my answer, hope it would be helpful to your problem~